# Markdown formatting: how can I add a string after a bulleted list?

Tags: github, markdown, newline

I'm editing a GitHub wiki page using the Markdown edit mode.

The source is the following:

````
Parameters:
* ```param1```: string, contains a parameter 
* ```param2```: string, contains a parameter
* ```param3```: string, contains a parameter, could be:
   - `ONE`: one element.
   - `TWO`: two elements.
````

The result is the following:

- `param1`: string, contains a parameter
- `param2`: string, contains a parameter
- `param3`: string, contains a parameter, could be:

  - `ONE`: one element.
  - `TWO`: two elements.

Now I would like to add the following sentence, as an additional explanation for `param3`: "`param3` could be an empty string", so that the sentence is aligned with the third dot (before `param3`).

The best solution I've found is the following:

- `param1`: string, contains a parameter
- `param2`: string, contains a parameter
- `param3`: string, contains a parameter, could be:

  - `ONE`: one element.
  - `TWO`: two elements.

  `param3` could be an empty string

But, for some reason, it adds an extra space above "- `ONE`: one element.".

I can't find the right syntax either on GitHub, nor here on Stack Overflow.

Comment: For inline code snippets use a single back tick as opposed to three.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should shift the paragraph to the right with non-breaking spaces to have it aligned with top-level list items.

```
 - `param1`: string, contains a parameter 
 - `param2`: string, contains a parameter 
 - `param3`: string, contains a parameter, could be:
    - `ONE`: one element.
    - `TWO`: two elements.

&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;`param3` could be an empty string
```

**Result:**

- `param1`: string, contains a parameter
- `param2`: string, contains a parameter
- `param3`: string, contains a parameter, could be:

  - `ONE`: one element.
  - `TWO`: two elements.

`param3` could be an empty string

Comment: What I would like to achieve (sorry if I've not explained myself correctly) is to have the "param3 could be an empty string" aligned with the string "param3: string, contains a parameter, could be:" since it's an additional information about that parameter. In your solution, instead, it seems that the string "param3 could be an empty string" is an another point the the sublist "ONE: one element.", "TWO: two elements."

Comment: Thank for the updated answer. It adds some extra space between the 2 lines "TWO: two elements." and "param3 could be an empty string" but it seems to be the best solution

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are mixing "loose" and "tight" list items... and Stackoverflow has some odd CSS rules.

## Tight lists

A "tight list item" is a list item which is not wrapped in a paragraph (`<p>`) in the HTML output. A tight list is created by not including blank lines between items.

For example this list:

```
* item one
* item two
```

... is rendered as this HTML:

```
<ul>
  <li>item one</li>
  <li>item two</li>
</ul>
```

Note that no `<p>` tags appear in that list.

## Loose lists

A "loose list item" is a list in which each item is wrapped in a paragraph (`<p>`) in the HTML output. A loose list is created by including a blank line between each list item.

For example this list:

```
* item one

* item two
```

... is rendered as this HTML:

```
<ul>
  <li><p>item one<p></li>
  <li><p>item two<p></li>
</ul>
```

Note that the contents of each list item `<li>` is wrapped in a `<p>` tag. This generally caused additional whitespace to display in the browser. For example, here on Stackoverflow the following CSS rule is defined:

```
p {margin-bottom: 1em;}
```

That rule causes a wide bottom margin which separates the paragraph from the content following it. However, that rule is not applied to tight list items (as there is no `<p>` tag) and they are much closer together.

## You have a "mixed" list

A "mixed list" is a list which includes both types of items. Some items are wrapped in `<p>` tags and some are not. It's important to note that any list item which contains nested items is a "loose list item". However, your other items are "tight list items" and for that reason you have a mixed list which appears to be inconsistent. You need to make all items either "tight" or "loose". Of course, as you have no choice but to make the third item "loose" (as it has nested items), you must then make all items "loose". It even helps to have the nested sub-list be loose.

Like this:

```
Parameters:

* `param1`: string, contains a parameter 

* `param2`: string, contains a parameter

* `param3`: string, contains a parameter, could be:

    - `ONE`: one element.

    - `TWO`: two elements.

    `param3` could be an empty string
```

## But this doesn't appear to work on Stackoverflow...

Stackoverflow has this (weird, IMO) CSS rule:

```
ul p.last-of-type {margin-bottom: 0;}
```

Which causes the last paragraph of a list to not get the wide bottom margin. Of course, the paragraph following your nested list is then really close to the nested list above it, instead of maintaining the same spacing as all other items in the list. Due to this rule, there is nothing you can do to "fix" the problem except beg the stackoverflow devs to change the CSS (at the very least, the rule should only apply to lists at the root level of a question/answer, but not to nested lists).

Fortunately, not all sites use that unusual rule and using a loose list on other sites should be more consistent.