# Markdown: Is it possible to put a list in tight to preceding paragraph?

Tags: markdown, github-flavored-markdown

I know whitespace is king in markdown. But is there a way to nest a list to a preceding paragraph.
e.g.

```
distant learning:
*   distance
*   commonality
```

Renders as:

```
distant learning:

    ⋅ distance
    ⋅ commonality
```

And what I would like to do produce is:

```
distant learning:
    ⋅ distance
    ⋅ commonality
```

Is this even possible in markdown? If so, how?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Markdown formatting: how can I add a string after a bulleted list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48931957/markdown-formatting-how-can-i-add-a-string-after-a-bulleted-list)

Comment: Not exactly. I can achieve the results I want in a nested list, but 'snugging' the list up into a preceding paragraph, that is not a list item, does not appear to be possible, using correct markdown syntax. I am sure I could coerce a result that looks right with &emsp; or &nbsp;.